# CSS box with text across the top

Tags: html, css

I want to create a box in html, but place text across the top border, to achieve the effect shown here:

[desired effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuZrq.jpg)

[image]

But I am getting this instead. The text background color is there, but the border is going in front of the text instead of behind it:

[current situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5PFW.jpg)

[image]

Here is my code:

```css
.box_div h3 {
  display: table;
  margin: -25px auto 28px auto;
  background-color: #FFF;
  font-size: 33px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box_div">
  <h3>Text Goes Here</h3>
  <p>Inner text goes here</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks fine here:  https://jsfiddle.net/as090tLf/

Comment: I'd recommend you use `display: inline-block;` instead of `display: table;` on the `h3` and `text-align: center;` on the parent.

Comment: I might do it [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/1gr7rgmc/).